# Two very similar object.extend() codes to fill a list, one works one does not

Tags: python, list, if-statement

The program below should put words in a list. The test for it to work is 'print(allwords[1])'. Funny thing is that the bottom part works, but when I use the top part it does not. The list apparently stays empty. How is what I am doing any different?

```
# DOES NOT WORK
print ('On what difficulty do you want to play?\n')
diffculty = input('1.Easy\n2.Medium\n3.Hard\n\n')
if diffculty == 1 or input == 'Easy' or input == 'easy' or input == 'EASY':
    with open('google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-short.txt') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            allwords.extend(line.strip().split(','))
elif diffculty == 2 or input == 'Medium' or input == 'medium' or input == 'MEDIUM':
    with open('google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-medium.txt') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            allwords.extend(line.strip().split(','))
elif diffculty == 3 or input == 'Hard' or input == 'hard' or input == 'HARD':
    with open('google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-long.txt') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            allwords.extend(line.strip().split(','))

# WORKS
print ('Okay then, let us begin with your first word.\n')
with open('google-10000-english-usa-no-swears-long.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        allwords.extend(line.strip().split(','))

print (allwords[1])
```

So the problem was actually the IF-statement.I made two changes and now it works.
 1. I made the if statement check for string numbers ('1')
 2. I corrected the if variables (they should all be diffculty)
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Does the code withing the `if statement`s run? Did you try printing out something in there for testing?

Comment: That is a very good question. I just checked (put a print 1,2,3 in after each if) and they do not. But seriously, why don't they?

Comment: Your first comparison in each `if statement` is wrong. You try to compare a string to an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `if statement`.

Try placing it with

```
if diffculty == '1' or input == 'Easy' or input == 'easy' or input == 'EASY':
```

Notice the `1` is withing strings now

The `input` is stored as a string and you are trying to compare it with an `int`.

Also, like @zwer mentioned in his answer, it is better to convert the user input into lowercase for comparison. So, you don't have to worry about comparing multiple possibilities of the same word. You can try something like:

```
print ('On what difficulty do you want to play?\n')
diffculty = input('1.Easy\n2.Medium\n3.Hard\n\n')

#The code below converts the user input to lower case. If example the user types 
# HARD or Hard or harD or something it converts it to 'hard'

diffculty = diffculty.lower()

print(diffculty)

if diffculty == '1' or diffculty == 'easy':
    print('easy')
    #do your easy code
elif diffculty == '2' or diffculty == 'medium':
    print('medium')
    #do your medium code
elif diffculty == '3' or  diffculty == 'hard':
    print('hard')
    #do your hard code
else:
  print('Please enter the correct difficulty level')
```

Comment: Your answer fixed it, because of the same reason as the previous comment I assume. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Please check my recent edit to the answer

Answer (score 0):

`input()` gives you a string, so you need to convert it into an int before doing your `difficulty == 1` and similar checks:

```
difficulty = int(input('1.Easy\n2.Medium\n3.Hard\n\n'))
```

You might want to add some additional validation.

Also, `input()` is a function so checking if `input == 'Hard'` makes no sense. If you want to account for 'all' eventualities from user input, do something like:

```
difficulty = input('1.Easy\n2.Medium\n3.Hard\n\n').lower()  # turn input to lowercase
if difficulty in ("1", "easy"):
    # your easy code
elif difficulty in ("2", "medium"):
    # your medium code
elif difficulty in ("3", "hard"):
    # your hard code
else:
    # wrong input...
```

Comment: It is supposed to be a user input to change the difficulty of the game. Can you explain why it makes no sense?

Comment: @TomKisters - you were using `input` instead of your `difficulty` variable on all consequent checks in your `if` statements (it should be `difficulty == 'Hard'`, not `input == 'Hard'` etc.). Probably a typo. Either way, you need to compare like with like, so do as above - deal with strings only.

Comment: I used the answer below, which if I am correct also fixes the issue you mentioned. Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: You are correct, I noticed a bit late that I was using the wrong term to check. I figured it out when I was revisiting the code. I still did not see it when you pointed it out haha.